# Issue with Complex Multi-Join Query

Tags: postgresql

I have a problem with multi-join queries.
I thinking, and testing many solution, but I waiting for result +1h and nothing.
Anyone have idea, how I can fix it, maybe I should change my database structure?

- query
  https://gist.github.com/mxcdh/d4ea7f98236e4a6ad084b9d1a2eaa7d9#file-postgres_query-sql
- schema.prisma
  https://gist.github.com/mxcdh/d4ea7f98236e4a6ad084b9d1a2eaa7d9#file-schema-prisma
- what I want returned:
  https://gist.github.com/mxcdh/d4ea7f98236e4a6ad084b9d1a2eaa7d9#file-return-md
- database table overview
  https://gist.github.com/mxcdh/d4ea7f98236e4a6ad084b9d1a2eaa7d9#file-database_overview-md

Comment: Why don't you post the entire question here on SO?

Comment: @FrankHeikens what is SO?

Comment: That would be StackOverflow, your original question in one piece over here.